# Accessing notebook cell metadata and HTML class attributes in JupyterLab Extensions

Tags: jupyter-lab

In a minimum viable JupyterLab extension, as for example tested using the [JupyterLab Plugin Playground](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-plugin-playground), how can I add a toolbar button that will toggle a particular class attribute on the HTML associated with one or more selected notebook cells (either code cell or markdown cell)?

To generalise the example further:

- how would I apply different class attributes to code cells and markdown cells?
- how would I add a class to the HTML based on the the presence of a particular metadata attribute or metadata tag element in the notebook JSON structure?

As a starting point the following code (taken from the JupyterLab [extension examples](https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples/blob/master/toolbar-button/src/index.ts)) should add a button to the toolbar:

```py
import { IDisposable, DisposableDelegate } from '@lumino/disposable';

import {
  JupyterFrontEnd,
  JupyterFrontEndPlugin,
} from '@jupyterlab/application';

import { ToolbarButton } from '@jupyterlab/apputils';

import { DocumentRegistry } from '@jupyterlab/docregistry';

import {
  NotebookActions,
  NotebookPanel,
  INotebookModel,
} from '@jupyterlab/notebook';

/**
 * The plugin registration information.
 */
const plugin: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  activate,
  id: 'toolbar-button',
  autoStart: true,
};

/**
 * A notebook widget extension that adds a button to the toolbar.
 */
export class ButtonExtension
  implements DocumentRegistry.IWidgetExtension<NotebookPanel, INotebookModel>
{
  /**
   * Create a new extension for the notebook panel widget.
   *
   * @param panel Notebook panel
   * @param context Notebook context
   * @returns Disposable on the added button
   */
  createNew(
    panel: NotebookPanel,
    context: DocumentRegistry.IContext<INotebookModel>
  ): IDisposable {
    const myButtonAction = () => {
      // Perform some action
    };

    const button = new ToolbarButton({
      className: 'my-action-button',
      label: 'My Button',
      onClick: myButtonAction,
      tooltip: 'Perform My Button action',
    });

    panel.toolbar.insertItem(10, 'myNewAction', button);
    return new DisposableDelegate(() => {
      button.dispose();
    });
  }
}

/**
 * Activate the extension.
 *
 * @param app Main application object
 */
function activate(app: JupyterFrontEnd): void {
  app.docRegistry.addWidgetExtension('Notebook', new ButtonExtension());
}

/**
 * Export the plugin as default.
 */
export default plugin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall start by getting a handle of the [`Notebook`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classes/notebook.notebook-2.html) class instance (which is the content of the notebook `panel` which you already have available):

```js
// in anonymous function assigned to myButtonAction
const notebook = panel.content;
```

The notebook instance provides you with the active [`Cell`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classes/cells.cell-1.html) widget:

```js
const activeCell = notebook.activeCell;
```

The cell widget has two attributes of interest: `model` which enables you to access the metadata, and `node` which enables manipulation of the DOM structure.

For example, you could toggle class of the node of a cell if it is a markdown cell (=[`ICellModel`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/interfaces/cells.icellmodel.html) has `.type` ([`CellType`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/modules/nbformat.html#celltype)) equal to `'markdown'`):

```js
if (activeCell.model.type === 'markdown') {
   activeCell.node.classList.toggle('someClass');
}
```

The metadata is stored in `cell.model.metadata`.

For selection of cells something as follows should work:

```js
const {head, anchor} = notebook.getContiguousSelection();
if (head === null || anchor === null) {
  // no selection
  return;
}
const start = head > anchor ? anchor : head;
const end = head > anchor ? head : anchor;
for (let cellIndex = start; cellIndex <= end; cellIndex++) {
  const cell = notebook.widgets[cellIndex];
  if (cell.model.type === 'code') {
      cell.node.classList.toggle('someOtherClass');
  }
}
```

There is a problem with this approach however, as when the notebook gets opened in a separate view, or simply reloaded, the classes will go away (as they are only toggled on the DOM nodes). If you require persistence, I would recommend to:

- use the button to only write to cell metadata
- add a separate callback function which will listen to any changes to the notebook model, roughly (not tested!):

  ```js
  // in createNew()
  const notebook = panel.content;
  notebook.modelChanged.connect((notebook) => {
    // iterate cells and toggle DOM classes as needed, e.g.
    for (const cell of notebook.widgets) {
      if (cell.model.metadata.get('someMetaData')) {
        cell.node.classList.toggle('someOtherClass');
      }
    }
  });
  ```

  which should also work (in principle) with collaborative editing.

Comment: @krassowksi Thanks, that was really helpful. Is the metadata only readable or can the toggle button function write to it? Also, is there a way to navigate to other (child) elements of the HTML cell structure from the CELL.node accessor?

Comment: Presumably, notebook.modelChanged is fired if the notebook is changed whilst it's open in the editor. If I want to check all cell metadata elements when the notebook is first opened into the editor, is there a notebook.ready or similar that I can connect to ?

Comment: Ah, to answer my own second question, notebook.fullyRendered maybe?

Comment: I believe you can write to metadata too. You can navigate to child elements using the standard DOM methods, or better use the Cell accessors (like `.editor`, `.editorWidget`, `.inputArea.node`, `.inputArea.promptNode`, etc.

Comment: `notebook.fullyRendered` is fairly new and may not be what you are looking for. Previously there was no concept of "notebook.ready" (it was just cells getting added one by one on load), but with the virtualized rendering - if configured to rely solely on content intersection) users may never see a fully rendered notebook (if they do not scroll down to the very last cell); in any case this is all subject to change based on the feedback we got about problems with this feature (a lot of changes were already made), so personally I would just go one-by-one on every change.

Comment: so will modelChanged always fire when a notebook is loaded ? (Whenever I open a notebook, I want to iterate the cells and check the metadata tags). Race conditions in the UI we one of bugbears of interacting extensions in classic nb and IIRC a big claim made early for JupyterLab was it would offer a more stable way of doing things... Re: metadata  - yep, seems to work ( .metadata.set(k,v); thanks again:-)

Comment: If I watch for change, and I iterate all cells each change, if a change is fired as new cells are added, I will have checked metadata on the first cell num_cells times? On a change, can I get just the cell that changed?

Comment: Yes, there is a computational burden, but I would advise to start with that. If you need to optimise for performance then indeed you can listen to `notebook.model.cells.changed` event, but handling of that signal data could be a bit... demanding. See my [`handle_cell_change`](https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp/blob/dd7c41b915588a30fd0363cc3da13c43179d4d8d/packages/jupyterlab-lsp/src/adapters/notebook/notebook.ts#L183-L284) method for an example (it only operates on model level so you would need to get widgets for these cell models).